# plugin doesn't work when page is called by jquery load method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a page called **index.php**, this page is only a menu and a div with the id index_work. When any item in the menu is clicked, i use the load method to load a second page named **relatorios.php**.

The page **relatorios.php** uses a plugin, the jquery datepicker. here is some code from both pages:

index.php:

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
  <li class="sidebar-brand">
    <a href="#"> Menu Title </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="linkInformativos">Informativos</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" id="linkRelatorios"> Relatórios </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="index_work"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#linkRelatorios").click(function(){
  $("#index_work").load("relatorios.php"); 
});

</script>
```

relatorios.php:

```
<!-- jqueryui datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../plugin/jquery-ui/datepicker.min.css">   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/jquery-ui/datepicker.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="dataAtendimentos" >

<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#dataAtendimentos").datepicker();

  //some other JavaScript that always work
</script>
```

If i go on the browser and type the whole address: "localhost/myproject/**relatorios.php** everything works all the time.

If i go to **index.php** and click the menu to load **relatorios.php** the plugin datepicker only works the first time i click the menu, the rest of the times the input works as a text, instead of a datepicker.

So these are the steps:

1. go to index.php
2. click on the menu item linkRelatorios (here the page **relatorios.php** is loaded and everything works fine
3. click on the menu item linkInformativos (another page is loaded on the div and works fine)
4. click the menu item linkRelatorios again (the page **relatorios.php** is loaded, everything works as expected, except the datepicker plugin)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You might try wrapping your code in `$(document).ready()` in relatorios.php

```
$(function() {
   $("#dataAtendimentos").datepicker();
})
```

The DOM is probabely not loaded yet at the time you call datepicker.

Comment: still didn't work, i had already tried this, but then i thought that if this was the problem, it wouldn't work the first time i clicked the menu item. It would also not work if i go directly to the page, but thanks :)